# How to unit test to give coverage of exception branches

Tags: unit-testing, exception, junit4, mockito, robolectric

I write unit tests with JUnit4 and Mockito for my application and I want make full coverage. But I don't fully understand how cover exception branches.
For example:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How I can invoke from tests exceptions?

Comment: It just exception example. I mean invoke any exception

Comment: It depends on the code that could throw the exception and the kind of exception you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you may not easily be able to insert an exception into `Thread.sleep` in particular, because it's being called statically instead of against an injected instance, you can easily stub injected dependencies to throw exceptions when called:

```
@Test
public void shouldHandleException() throws Exception {
  // Use "thenThrow" for the standard "when" syntax.
  when(dependency.someMethod()).thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException());

  // Void methods can't use "when" and need the Yoda syntax instead.
  doThrow(new IllegalArgumentException()).when(dependency).someVoidMethod();

  SystemUnderTest system = new SystemUnderTest(dependency);
  // ...
}
```