# How do I run a JUnit Test on the exception handlers of a method and when a function normally uses a file for input?

Tags: java, unit-testing, file-io, junit, exception

I am trying to write a Unit test for testing a  method's exception handlers, but I am unsure how to go about this.

The functions containing the exception handlers to be tested call other functions (that get their input from a file) for some of their input (not passed within the parameters of the tested function, but returned to the function).  The parameter passed to the function being tested is the filename of the input to be used by the other functions (which is passed to them when they are called).

I may be having trouble explaining so here are some examples of one of the functions that I want to test (I know that this looks like a test itself that I am testing, but it is a different kind of test):

```
/**
 * Returns value of a property defined in test.properties file.
 * If the property's name ends in "!encrypted" it is assumed to be encryptd and will be decrypted
 * @param propertyName  name of property
 * @return Value of property, or null if property is not found
 */
public static String getProperty(String propertyName) {
    if (testProperties == null) {  //load properties if not already loaded
        synchronized(PropertyUtil.class) {
            if (testProperties == null) { 
                testProperties = loadPropertiesFile("/test-resources/test.properties");
            }
        }
    }
    String propValue = testProperties.getProperty(propertyName);
    if (propertyName.endsWith("!encrypted"))
        return decryptProperty(propValue);
    else
        return propValue;
}

/**
 * Returns value of a property defined in test.properties file.
 * If the property's name ends in "!encrypted" it is assumed to be encryptd and will be decrypted
 * @param propertyName name of property
 * @param defaultValue default value to return if property is not found
 * @return Value of property, or defaultValue if property is not found
 */
public static String getProperty(String propertyName, String defaultValue) {
    String propValue = getProperty(propertyName);
    if (propValue == null)
        return defaultValue;
    else
        return propValue;
}

/**
 * Load the given properties file into a Properties object.
 * Use this if you need to load properties from files other than the default test.properties
 * @param filename
 *            is the name of a resource filename, relative to the classpath.
 * 
 * @throws RuntimeException
 *             if the properties can't be loaded.
 */
public static Properties loadPropertiesFile(String filename) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    InputStream in = null;

    try {
        in = PropertyUtil.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
        props.load(in); // warning: assumes ISO8859-1 charset as per docs
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("can't load properties file: " + filename, e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("can't close properties file: " + filename, e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    return props;
}
```

How do I make sure an exception handler throws an exception when it is supposed to and doesn't throw when it is not supposed to using Unit testing?

For testing in general should I use the files that have the input in the Unit test (and are fetched by other methods), create files specifically for the test and pass the whole argument for a function manually using input I specify in the unit test function itself (putting data in parentheses and passing that to a copy of the function that doesn't use a file name as an argument instead and isolate method from other methods)?

Should I use assertion statements, and if so, what should they look like?

Comment: Posible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149519/how-should-a-unit-test-deal-with-expected-and-unexpected-exceptions/24149620#24149620

Comment: Externalize the business logic of the handler to a separate method or class and then perform JUnit tests against those methods

Comment: @cluemein you might be looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751139/how-to-unit-test-to-give-coverage-of-exception-branches

Comment: why was this closed as unclear?  It may have been a duplicate, but then why not merge it simply with the other one?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear what I was asking and correct some grammar, so please reopen and remove downvotes.  Also, there is a very good answer and explanation below, so it should be helpful.

Comment: Also this question is definitely not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149519/how-should-a-unit-test-deal-with-expected-and-unexpected-exceptions/24149620#24149620 .  It may be a duplicate of the other one, but that one I found difficult to read, partly due I think to the asker not having English as their native toungue.

Comment: Can you break your sentences into smaller bits, please? It is very difficult to follow what you are asking.

Comment: Is that better Schorsch?

Comment: @cluemein I can't answer the question as I don't know java, but it is very likely that your question was closed as "unclear" not because your wording is unclear, but because what you are asking is unclear.  You really haven't explain what you are trying to do or where you are stuck.  You've only described a general concept that you want someone to explain to you.  These types of questions do not make good questions for Stack Overflow.

Comment: *"should I use the files that have the input ... create files ... for the test, or pass the whole argument for a function manually using input I specify ... (putting data in parentheses and passing that to a copy of the function that doesn't use a file name as an argument instead)?* What does this mean? Could you describe in code (or pseudocode) what you had in mind for these possibilities? Or perhaps an example of a method that you want to test in this way? Did you try anything; if so, what results did you get?

Comment: *"I am trying to write a Unit test for a method's exception handlers."* What do you specifically mean by this - are you trying to test that a method throws an exception? Trying to test that a method handles an exception appropriately? An example of code you wish to test would be helpful, as well as specific conditions you need to verify in the unit test.

Comment: @CarlVeazey Is the question more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a very good usecase where thinking about unit tests forces you to design your app better. I think you can break down your logic of processing the files into smaller units(functions or different classes if possible). Then you should try to write "unit-tests" for each of those units.

On the side note, for checking if the exception was thrown in your unit tests - your method should be throwing the exceptions and all clients of that method (your other code that uses that method, your unit tests) should expect that exception to be thrown and either catch it or re-throw it as you deem fit. In case of unit tests - you can catch that exception and put some validation assertion there. You can have an invalid assertion just after making the call to this method and if the exception is not thrown, then your unit test will move to next line and it will fail there. See below:

```
your unitTest()
{
 try {
  // make a call to the method you want to test
    yourMethod.call(inputToAllowException);
    Assert.assertEquals(1 , 0); // you should not reach here if the exception was thrown
 } catch(YourException ye)
 {
  //assertion or print to say exception was thrown
 }
}
```

Comment: If you want to test for an exception then use use the framework's options for that, like `@expected(YourException.class)` in JUnit.

Comment: I haven't used such option (haven't worked on it much lately), so if this is available, then that's great.